# No power to motherboard

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

I moved my computer this morning and it initially started up to the CMOS setup screen ("Press F1 to run setup, F2 to continue..."). However the keyboard wasn't connected properly, and while I was hooking it up the computer shut down. Not sure if it timed out or lost power some other way.

Now the MB isn't getting power at all (no standby light). I checked the PSU with the paperclick method and with a multimeter and everything came out out fine. I reconnected the power cables and made sure there aren't any stray wires touching the MB to create a short.  I've been using this computer for a couple years with no problems, so the hardware is all compatible.

What are next steps to try? Could something have happened to the firmware?

MB: MSI Z97-GAMING 5 ATX LGA1150

PSU: EVGA - SuperNOVA NEX 650W 80+ Gold

Comment: Power supplies with a lot of dust in them don't like being moved - Do you have another to try out?

Comment: I pulled everything out and rebuilt it and it's going fine now - something must have gotten knocked loose.  I'm definitely going to leave it in place from here on out though

Answer (score 0):

I pulled everything out and rebuilt it and it's going fine now - something must have gotten knocked loose. I'm definitely going to leave it in place from here on out though